# Is pypy compatible with tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pypy

I am looking for a wheel compatible with pypy, without success.

```
pypy3 -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/28/96efba1a516cdacc2e2d6d081f699c001d414cc8ca3250e6d59ae657eb2b/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: tensorflow-1.14.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Configs:

```
➜  pypy3 --version
Python 3.6.9 (7.3.0+dfsg-1~ppa1~ubuntu19.04, Dec 26 2019, 11:14:16)
[PyPy 7.3.0 with GCC 8
```

If the wheel doesn't exist should I build tensorflow from sources ?
Will it be reconized by pypy ?

Comment: At the moment, [Tensorflow is not compatible with pypy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/252)